# Arduino connection via /dev/ttyACM0 not working

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I have troubles to connect to arduino UNO via Arduino IDE on Ubuntu
Of course ports are greyed out, but I set it up manually.
When I try to upload I get following information:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException thrown while loading
gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver processing.app.SerialNotFoundException: Serial
port '/dev/ttyACM0' not found. Did you select the right one from the
Tools > Serial Port menu?
```

Installed packages:

```
$ apt list --installed |grep arduino
arduino/bionic,bionic,now 2:1.0.5+dfsg2-4.1 all [installed]
arduino-core/bionic,bionic,now 2:1.0.5+dfsg2-4.1 all [installed]
arduino-mk/bionic,bionic,now 1.5.2-1 all [installed]
$
```

I am member of dialout group:

```
$ cat /etc/group |grep marcin
uucp:x:10:marcin
dialout:x:20:marcin
fax:x:21:marcin
audio:x:29:pulse,marcin,timidity
dip:x:30:marcin,marcin
video:x:44:marcin
plugdev:x:46:marcin
marcin:x:1001:
```

Port /dev/ttyACM0 is the proper one:

```
$ ls -l /dev/ttyACM0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 paź 12 20:54 /dev/ttyACM0
$

dmesg output:
[ 1033.897893] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 1034.051751] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=0043, bcdDevice= 0.01
[ 1034.051768] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=220
[ 1034.051780] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Arduino (www.arduino.cc)
[ 1034.051789] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 9573xxxxxxxxxxxx
[ 1034.112081] cdc_acm 1-1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[ 1034.114359] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[ 1034.114363] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
```

Arduino preferences files related to port:

```
$ cat .arduino/preferences.txt |grep serial
serial.databits=8
serial.debug_rate=9600
serial.parity=N
serial.port=/dev/ttyACM0
serial.stopbits=1
$
```

USB devices:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:5608 Alcor Micro Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 258a:000c  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2341:0043 Arduino SA Uno R3 (CDC ACM)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
$
```

Computer has been restarted, USB cable was pluged in and out several times with IDE turned on and off, No more ideas on how to move forward.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe relevant? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rxtx/+bug/1770604 (Separately, TIL what ACM in ttyACM stands for, so thanks for that. :))

Comment: Separately, can you interact with the serial port from the command line (for example, using `screen`)?

Comment: unpack Arduino IDE from download from arduino.cc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the bug pointed by NPE and it solved the issue.

I installed librxtx-java package from bionic-proposed repository

```
$ sudo apt-get install librxtx-java/bionic-proposed
```

Now connection works smoothly. Thank you!